# google map default showing one location

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps

I am trying to show a location in google map for given lat and longitude. The problem is it is showing default one location and if I navigate to my location (for given lat and long) explicitly then I could see the marker and title on it.

I am expecting as it should show the location of given lat and long in first shot.
But by default it is showing some where near greenland.

As i don't have required no of reputations I could not post the images here.

Below is my code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    double latitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("lat", 0);
    double longitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("lng", 0);
    Log.d("Zumbare","lat value : "+latitude);
    Log.d("Zumbare","lng value : "+longitude);

    LatLng position = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
    options.position(position);
    options.title("Position");
    options.snippet("Latitude:"+latitude+",Longitude:"+longitude);
    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));


    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    GoogleMap googleMap = fm.getMap();
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

    googleMap.addMarker(options);
    CameraUpdate updatePosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position);
    CameraUpdate updateZoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(5);
    googleMap.moveCamera(updatePosition);
    googleMap.animateCamera(updateZoom);
}
```

Can someone let me know the problem here.

Edit:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
}
```

Logs:

```
04-18 12:52:13.535    2566-2581/com.app.maptest.gmap W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-18 12:52:13.536    2566-2581/com.app.maptest.gmap W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9fa6cc00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-18 12:52:17.527    2566-2566/com.app.maptest.gmap I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services package version: 7097470
04-18 12:52:17.556    2566-2566/com.app.maptest.gmap D/Zumbare﹕ lat value : 16.474311
04-18 12:52:17.556    2566-2566/com.app.maptest.gmap D/Zumbare﹕ lng value : 80.712814
04-18 12:52:17.963    2566-2581/com.app.maptest.gmap W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-18 12:52:17.963    2566-2581/com.app.maptest.gmap W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa58ff100, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-18 12:52:21.485    2566-2697/com.app.maptest.gmap D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa0593ba0, tid 2697
04-18 12:52:21.516    2566-2566/com.app.maptest.gmap I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 229 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-18 12:52:24.522    2566-2578/com.app.maptest.gmap I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2035(112KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(258KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 24MB/24MB, paused 2.269ms total 420.232ms
04-18 12:52:24.666    2566-2578/com.app.maptest.gmap I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 823(72KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(5MB) LOS objects, 17% free, 18MB/22MB, paused 2.026ms total 139.787ms
```

Edit2:

```
package com.app.maptest.gmap;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    double latitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("lat", 0);
        double longitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("lng", 0);

        Log.d("Zumbare","lat value : "+latitude);
        Log.d("Zumbare","lng value : "+longitude);

        LatLng position = new LatLng(16.474311,80.712814);

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
        options.position(position);
        options.title("Position");
        options.snippet("Latitude:"+latitude+",Longitude:"+longitude);
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));


        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        GoogleMap googleMap = fm.getMap();
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

        googleMap.addMarker(options);
        CameraUpdate updatePosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position);
        CameraUpdate updateZoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(5);
        googleMap.moveCamera(updatePosition);
        googleMap.animateCamera(updateZoom);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `Zumbare` log entries?

Comment: com.app.maptest.gmap D/Zumbare﹕ lat value : 16.474311
com.app.maptest.gmap D/Zumbare﹕ lng value : 80.712814

Comment: Is your input for second time is 16.47431 and 80.712814??

Comment: Did you try debug or entering hard coded entry at the map. Also enter your log so we can understand.

Comment: What version of Google Maps API are you using?

Comment: I didn't get what do you mean by 2nd time. these values are coming from another activity from GUI and will go into latlong constructor dynamically.

Comment: Added logs and version details

Comment: Its same even after harcoding.

Comment: That place is in India.

Comment: Try to use newer version of google maps instead of `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'`. Change it to: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'`

Comment: can you post your whole activity code and where you have hardcoded your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code using Google Maps API v2, and got the same results as you.
Note that from your gradle file it looks like you're using an older API, but your log file indicates that you might be using API v2.

I fixed it by making these changes, give it a try and see if it works for you:

```
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(options);//keep this

        //remove lines below:
        //CameraUpdate updatePosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position);
        //CameraUpdate updateZoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(5);
        //googleMap.moveCamera(updatePosition);
        //googleMap.animateCamera(updateZoom);

        //use this instead:
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(position).zoom(5).build();

        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```